# Hive Database Disappearing When Restarting Flutter App

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-hive

We are using a Hive database for our Flutter project. It mostly works well. However, we've noticed that sometimes after a restart, the database just disappears and has to be recreated. Some restarts are OK. Other times the database is just gone. It's a bit frustrating.

Is this something that happens on the Android simulator only? Will we see this in open production? Whenever a user downloads an app update?

Comment: This sounds more like a support question for the hive team than a stack-overflow question TBH.

Comment: Had the same issue a long time ago, and was time constrainer, just jumpled into sqflite or moor(way more stable). You can check out objectbox if you prefer non relational

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll keep researching. It's still an inconsistent thing, and annoying. If I was certain it would not happen on a prod app, I'd be OK with it. I'll email the hive team.